# python using a dictionary to replace characters in a list of strings

Tags: python, dictionary, replace

I am trying to make a code breaking game where the user submits symbol/letter pairs to a dictionary to crack a code, I then want the code to use the dictionary to replace each instance of a symbol with the paired letter.

I have the following bits of code:

```
words = imported list of coded words where each letter is replaced by a symbol. from a text file so i can change later
clues = dictionary of symbol and letter pairs that can be added to, removed from
```

I have tried the following but it failed with: `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

```
def converter(words,clues):

    progression = words


    for words in progression:#cycles through each coded word in the list
        for key in clues: #for each symbol in the dictionary
            progression[words] = progression[words].replace(key, clues[key]) #replaces


    return progression
```

Any help that anyone could offer I would be very grateful.

Adam

Comment: You are re-using the same variable names for many different things, avoid this. Also - you mention dictionaries, but are using only lists.

Answer (score 2):

`progression` is a list. To access content from it, you need to use the index value, which is an integer, and not a string, hence the error.

You probably want:

```
for i, j in enumerate(words):
    words[i] = clues.get(j)
```

What enumerate does is loops through the list of words, where `i` is the index value and `j` is the content. `.get()` is similar to `dict['key']`, but if the key is not found it returns `None` instead of raising an error.

Then `words[i]` modifies the list with the index number of the word

Answer (score 1):

[Haidro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1971805/haidro) explained it pretty well, but I thought I'd expand his code, and also address another issue.

First off, as [Inbar Rose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1561176/inbar-rose) pointed out, your naming conventions bad.  It makes code much more difficult to read, debug, and maintain.  Pick concise descriptive names, and make sure to follow [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions.).  Avoid re-using the same variable name for different things, especially within the same scope.

Now, to the code:

```
words = ['Super', 'Random', 'List']
clues = {'R': 'S', 'd': 'r', 'a': 'e', 'o': 'e', 'm': 't', 'n': 'c'}


def decrypter(words, clues):

    progression = words[:]

    for i, word in enumerate(progression):
        for key in clues:
            progression[i] = progression[i].replace(key, clues.get(key))

    return progression
```

This now replaces characters in the content of `progression[i]` instead of replacing `progression[i]` with the key from `clues`.

Also, changed `progression = words` to `progression = words[:]` in order to create a copy of the list to act on.  You pass in a reference to words, and then assign that same reference to progression.  As you manipulate `progression`, so to do you manipulate `words`, rendering `progression` useless to be using in this case.

Example using:

```
print words
print decrypter(words, clues)
print words
```

Output using `progression = words`:

> ['Super', 'Random', 'List']
>   ['Super', 'Secret', 'List']
>   ['Super', 'Secret', 'List']

Output using `progression = words[:]`:

> ['Super', 'Random', 'List']
>   ['Super', 'Secret', 'List']
>   ['Super', 'Random', 'List']